# socket returning double input

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm new to socket programming in Java and I made a simple client/server with sockets in Java where client need to input the options to access the function in server and I have this problem where the server send double input but I just need one.

Can anyone help me? thanks.

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Server Started ....");
        while (true) {
            counter++;
            Socket serverClient = server.accept();
            // server accept the client connection request
            System.out.println(" >> " + "Client No:" + counter + " started!");
            DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(serverClient.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(serverClient.getOutputStream());
            ServerClientThread sct = new ServerClientThread(serverClient, counter, inStream,
                    outStream);
            // send the request to a separate thread
            sct.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

class ServerClientThread extends Thread {

    final Socket serverClient;
    final int clientNo;
    final DataInputStream inStream;
    final DataOutputStream outStream;


    ServerClientThread(Socket inSocket, int counter, DataInputStream inStream,
            DataOutputStream outStream) {
        this.serverClient = inSocket;
        this.clientNo = counter;
        this.inStream = inStream;
        this.outStream = outStream;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String clientMessage = "", serverMessage = "";
            while (!clientMessage.equals("bye")) {
                outStream.writeUTF("1,2,3:");
                clientMessage = inStream.readUTF();
                switch (clientMessage) {
                    case "1":
                        outStream.writeUTF("masukkan number:");
                        outStream.flush();
                        serverMessage = inStream.readUTF();
                        outStream.writeUTF(serverMessage);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("tidak ada pilihan!");
                }
            }
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            serverClient.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Client -" + clientNo + " exit!! ");
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String clientMessage = "", serverMessage = "";
        while (!clientMessage.equals("bye")) {
            System.out.println(inStream.readUTF());
            String input = br.readLine();
            outStream.writeUTF(input);
        }
        outStream.close();
        outStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Error on Client Side:

```
 1,2,3:
 1
 masukkan number:
 12
 12
 3
 1,2,3:
 1
 1,2,3:
 1
 masukkan number:
 12
 1
 13
 1,2,3:
 14
 1,2,3:
 15
```

Error on Server Side:

```
 Server Started ....
 Client No:1 started!
 tidak ada pilihan!
 tidak ada pilihan!
 tidak ada pilihan!
 tidak ada pilihan!
 tidak ada pilihan!
 tidak ada pilihan!
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 Client -1 exit!!
```

Comment: Please clarify which is "double input"?

Comment: Use a debugger and follow what is happening with the server and client writing and reading.

Comment: you can see in error client, Server should only send 1 input but it return 3      1,2,3: <<-- option
 1<<--option select
 masukkan number:
 12<client input
 12<-server input
 3<-here it return another value

Comment: that `3` is client input again

Comment: `1,2,3:` (server message) 
`1` (client input and message)
`masukkan number:` (server response)
`12` (client input and message)
`12` (server response)
`3` (client input and message)
`1,2,3:` (server response)

Comment: I'm much more interested in that connection reset. where the heck did it come from. strange, considering that the client loop never stops because "clientMessage" is never updated. wish i had my laptop nearby

Comment: ah, probably he just terminated the client manually